# A better way to generate pricing based on f(N)

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math, currency, in-app-purchase

I have in game currency in my game.  For a user to buy the next upgrade I currently use a very simple method whereby the Nth upgrade costs N*1000 coins.

Im not a massive fan of using this at the moment as I'd like it to be a bit easier to start off with and possibly scale better so its not quite as hard to get upgrades.

One solution would be to use Fibonnacci which gives great early results but would make later upgrades nigh on impossible.

Can anyone offer a solution as my maths knowledge is pretty limited

Answer (score 3):

What about [sigmoid function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html)? It starts to rise slowly, then it rises nearly linearly and at the end it starts to slow down.

If you look at the graph at wolfram alpha, you can calculate your price like this:

```
price = a_bit_more_than_maximum_upgrade_price * sigmoid( x )
```

You have to choose what multiple of the maximum price will be the price of the starting upgrade, if you choose starting `x=-4` you'll get some price less than 5% of maximum. Ending x could be equal to 4. You'll reach around 95% of maximum price. Then you have number of upgrades. You could calculate the input for sigmoid like this:

```
x = (upgrade_index / (number_of_upgrades-1)) * 8.0 - 4.0
```

Upgrade index is starting from zero and you have to have at least 2 upgrades :)
You can trim off last few digits or round them up to get nicer looking numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a question more related for http://programmers.stackoverflow.com

But anyway, I would say try use an exponential function, something like

```
f(n) = 1000 * 1.1^n
```

Obviously once you have 100 or more upgrades the price gets a bit ridiculous, you can then perhaps use a condition to check if `n` is larger than a certain number, then resume with your linear function to calculate the price of the next upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what sort of numbers would this generate?

Comment: The question is tagged with [objective-c], so note that `^` is *not* the exponentiation operator!

Comment: @MartinR OH... Im relatively new to Obj C.. whats ^ operator do?

Comment: @Chris: The "bitwise exclusive or" operator.

Comment: Im confused, doesnt the OP actually mean exponential in this case rather than XOR?

Comment: Yeah, sorry just thought it would be obvious to anyone that it's supposed to be exponential. As Martin R said, Objective-C doesn't support a native symbol for exponents, rather ^ is used as XOR and also blocks. If you want to use exponents then use the `pow(x, y)` function.